# jQuery's .serialize() doesn't do anything

Tags: jquery, serialization

I've got a fairly simple form with some checkboxes, radiobuttons and selectboxes. I want to post all the selected form-data using jQuery's $.ajax. But for some reason the form just doesn't get serialized. I'm not sure what's causing this... (Sidenote: `$('#FormID').submit(..)` doesn't work either with me). So I've created a button with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#DoSearchRequest').click(function(event) {
        //event.preventDefault(); // read about this somewhere, doesn't help
        $('#res').html($('#FormSearch').serialize()); // just some <p> to output the result to
        $.ajax({
            url:        'http://www.domain.nl/ajax/GetResultsBySearchRequest.php',
            data:       $('#FormSearch').serialize(),
            type:       'POST',
            success:    function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        },
            error: function(a, b, c) { console.log(a); }

        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

My button is outside the form (it doesn't matter if it's in the form either).

My form:

```
<form name="FormSearch" id="FormSearch" method="post">
... form elements
</form>
```

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 and jQueryUI 1.8.18

Comment: Are you saying the Ajax request is made, but on the server side you don't receive any data? Do your form elements have a `name` attribute? It would help if you showed the html for at least a few of the elements.

Comment: Yes, the success-function is reached. But the $_POST is empty in the PHP script. Form elements do have name-attributes (all of them). I don't think the problem lies there, because `$('#res').html()` is empty as well.

Comment: You don't have any other forms (or other elements) with the same id `"FormSearch"` do you? (If you do it is likely the first one that is serialised.) And you do have "successful" form fields, i.e., fields that are enabled, checkboxes that are checked, etc.?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: [Your code is working fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/gTxqm/), so can you please post the rest of it?

Comment: A preview is located http://www.bergenmeer.nl/index.php?pageId=SearchResult2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at your preview webpage I'd say the problem might be that you have nested form element "form543" inside another form element "searchbar".

Testing in Firefox, I found that `$("#form543").length` was `0` so jQuery obviously can't find the form at all. When I tried `$("#searchbar").serialize()` it returned actual field values for the select elements and the checkboxes that I'd checked and so forth.

I'd suggest removing the outer form element "searchbar" (or otherwise change the markup so you don't have nested forms) and see if your JS code works then.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally overlooked that part. While I'm optimizing I've copy-pasted the old container-structure, not mentioning a form-tag was already defined. Kinda sloppy of me, but thanks for telling me! +1 and accepted. Maybe a late reaction, but in Holland it was bedtime yesterday ;)

Answer (score 10):

Silly but for me it was that I didn't name the fields in my form so `.serialize` gave me an empty string, also `.serializeArray` didn't work.

Do **name** your form fields or you won't get any values.

```
<input name='importantField'/>
```

is not the same as

```
<input id='importantField'/>
```

`.serialize` or `.serializeArray` or even default form submit won't work if you haven't defined any names on your form fields.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make something like that :

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use name attribute for all your inputs in the form (including button)
E.g. `<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/>`

Then you can test if the `serial()` function works:

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
});
```

Then in Ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'SendAd.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),
})
```